# In storyboard is there a way to remove a hidden item from layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table cell with an image thumbnail (which may or not be hidden depending on if that row has an image) and a textView to the right of it.

Is there anyway to have the textView expand left to cover the area the image used to take when it was hidden without needing code?

Or another way to phrase it: in html you have hidden (visibility:hidden;) and removed  from layout (display:none;), it appears that view.hidden = NO does the css equivalent of hidden; I want the css equivalent of removed from layout.

Is there a no code solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in code with layout constraints. If you have a horizontal spacing constraint between your text view and image view, you can make an IBOutlet to it in IB, then change the value of its constant in code. So, in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, you would have some sort of if clause to test for whether you have an image for that row:

```
    if (indexPath.row %2 == 0) {
        cell.iv.hidden = YES;
        cell.imageViewToTextViewConstraint.constant = -48;
    }else{
        cell.iv.hidden = NO;
        cell.imageViewToTextViewConstraint.constant = 8;
    }
```

iv is my outlet to the cell's image view, and it's width is 48, so setting the constraint to -48 essentially expands the text view to where the left side of the image view is (the image view is still there, its just hidden). In this example I'm just setting the even rows to have no image, the odd rows have the one I set up in IB.

Answer (score 1):

No. HTML / CSS layout is quite advanced, you have to handle your textView frame (or constraints if you use `NSLayoutConstraint`) yourself when you set its content, with code.